# Windows 7 Window behavior in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Is it possible to get the windows 7 window behavior in ubuntu?

The specific part I'm talking about is the gestures thing where you can throw your window to one side and have it resize to take up that side, or to the top and have it maximize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly if it does this or not but the Compiz desktop effects should come built in now with the latest ubuntu distros, you might want to download the Compiz manager (which I don't think is installed automatically) which will allow you to toggle all kinds of behaviour. The compiz window manager gives all kinds of whizz bang desktop effects!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Compiz setting that enables this behaviour, I can't check those for you ATM, but it's there... the "Window Management" plugin perhaps.

On a related note, there is already [talk to implement this](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/21313/) as default behaviour in Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Grid' option in Compiz allows you to use key bindings for the behaviour you are looking for.

But this could be the solution:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html